# will the speed of hashMap.get ("The String key") be affected by the size of the hashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am coming up a very bold idea. That is I want to use a `HashMap` instead of Database to store data for a Chat App.

So, when the user send a chat message, the chat message of that particular user will be stored into a `HashMap` using `storeMsg()`.

Each user will have a separated chat room. Every 5 seconds, the chat room of that particular user will send a `getMsg()` method to retrieve the latest message inside that chat room. After it retrieve the message, it will **remove all the messages** relating to that chat room of that particular user so that we can avoid the overhead.

So, only users exist in that chat room can see the messages, the message can be just appended one by one. The new users who enter that chat room lately will not be able to see the previous messages. This is similar to peer to peer Chat.

Each user has a unique String username such as "tomhan12", "Mary2","123cat", etc.

```
public void storeMsg(String userName, String message){
   hMap.put(userName, message);
}

public String getMsg(String userName){
    return hMap.get(userName);
}
```

So, my question is that if the `hMap` has `Key`s that are `String`s & if that `hMap` has like millions of entries, then will speed of `hMap.get(str)` be affected?

Can we convert the `String userName` into a unique integer number & then "`hMap.put(thatUniqueIntegerNumber, message)`" for higher performance? or the HashMap did that for us so we don't need to do that?

Comment: `Can we convert the String userName into a unique integer number & then   "hMap.put(thatUniqueIntegerNumber, message)" for higher performance? or the HashMap did that for us so we don't need to do that?`

This is part of how the HashMap works to store your key,value pair

Comment: FYI: 5 seconds could be a very high time span to get the messages, because some users write only a few characters before sending the message like:hi, and whatsup in 2 summits.

Answer (score 8):

`HashMap`'s `get` has an expected constant running time, which means its running time shouldn't depend on the size of the `HashMap`. This, of course, relies on a decent implementation of the `hashCode` method of your key, but your key is `String`, so it shouldn't be a problem.

That said, using a large `HashMap` (or any other large data structure) consumes a large amount of memory, so you should pay attention that you are not running into lack of memory issues, which would slow down your application.

Comment: We insert the message then a few seconds later we remove that message the we can minimize the memory problem

Comment: @Tum You mentioned having million of entries. If those entries are large enough, they would require a substantial amount of memory.

Answer (score 3):

HashMap `get()` method provides O(1) time complexity if key `hashCode()` function has good distribution (it's true for strings). The size of the map does not affect operation performance (well technically when map gets bigger, collisions occur more often, but that's another story).

Replacing `String` keys with `Integer` keys will not give you any significant performance boost.

Comment: Yeah, 'guarantees' isn't quite right. To quote the docs: "This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets."

Comment: the guy is just storing strings, why do you bother him with extreme cases?

Comment: Then you should have written that "in case of Strings ...". Storing keys other than built-in Java classes (in which you provide your own hashCode() and equals(...)) isn't an extreme case at all.

Comment: We're not bothering him, we're bothering you for using the word "guaranteed" when it's trivial to show a case where this isn't true.

Comment: There is a huge significant change in performance if you use `int` as the key instead of `String`

Answer (score 1):

### According to the javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.
>
> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.
>
> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the operations of the HashMap class, including get and put). The expected number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.

Since HashMap stores its values in hash buckets, you can generally get between O(1) and O(N) for a lookup depending on the amount of hash collisions the map hash.

### Lets test this performance:

To test the performance of the Map, we going to run a test that first inserts 100/100000 items to the map, and then we call get("0-9") on the map in a loop to test the performance of the lookup. We use the following code to do this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class HashMapTest {
    public static void test(int items, boolean print) {
        System.gc();
        System.gc();
        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            map.put("" + i, map);
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            map.get("0");
            map.get("1");
            map.get("2");
            map.get("3");
            map.get("4");
            map.get("5");
            map.get("6");
            map.get("7");
            map.get("8");
            map.get("9");
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long time = end - start;
        if(print) {
            System.out.println("items: "+ items + " time: "+ time);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        // warmup
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            test(100, false);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            test(1000000, false);
        }
        // Real test:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            test(100, true);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            test(1000000, true);
        }
    }
}
```

### Test results

```
items: 100     time: 11102830
items: 100     time: 12228567
items: 100     time: 34309933
items: 100     time: 36976824
items: 100     time: 34290557
items: 100     time: 19819022
items: 100     time: 14747533
items: 100     time: 15818922
items: 100     time: 15026368
items: 100     time: 16830762
items: 1000000 time: 12421862
items: 1000000 time: 13931351
items: 1000000 time: 13083504
items: 1000000 time: 11453028
items: 1000000 time: 13265455
items: 1000000 time: 11030050
items: 1000000 time: 11362288
items: 1000000 time: 11521082
items: 1000000 time: 11198296
items: 1000000 time: 11303685

items 100     min: 11102830
items 100     max: 36976824
items 1000000 min: 11030050
items 1000000 max: 13931351
```

If we analyze the test results, we see no "real" improvement in the access time i we have a factor of 1000 more items.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically `HashMap#get(...)` has O(1) guaranteed, if the map isn't overpopulated and items are distributed properly among the buckets. Practical this is implementation-dependant, but usually the Map slows down a bit, if it's overpopulated. In general a `HashMap` should have a load-factor below 0.7 to avoid overpopulation and keep the performance optimal. The slow-down will be small though (except for some extreme cases).

Comment: How you can write "guaranteed" and "except for some extreme cases" in one paragraph...

Comment: the access time is O(1). This means that access is in constant-time regarding the size of the map. But there are cases where some entries collide, if `hash(A) mod p = hash(B) mod p`. These collisions always result in applying some sort of collision strategy, which will require additional processing. It's still O(1) though. Just the usual pitfall with runtime-complexity: it doesn't say anything about how the algorithm behaves exactly regarding to a specific case.

Comment: Sorry, but it is just your incorrect understanding of [Big_O_notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which describes worst case and number of colisions might not be constant regarding the map size...